# Ghost 301 redirecting www to non-www

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, ghost

I want to redirect my ghost aplication everytime it matches www.url to url. I've found [this](http://codenimbus.com/2014/01/15/redirecting-www-domain-to-non-www-on-ghost/) two-years post and tried to update the code. I inserted this snippet before the fist *router.get* (Admin routes), but it doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this? Ghost version is 0.7.4.

```
// 301 redirect from www to non-www
router.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    if(req.headers.host.match(/^www/) !== null) redirect301(res, 'http://' + req.headers.host.replace(/^www\./, '') + req.url);
});
```

Comment: How are you hosting Ghost? I have mine hosted on AWS so I'm using an A record to alias www to non-www on Route 53 - works a treat.

Perhaps you can use your own DNS to do that?

Comment: Is this on Pro or on your own server? If it is on your own server how are you running it? Are you using Nginx or HAProxy in front of it?

Comment: @JamesMurphy It's running on Heroku, with CloudFlare as DNS. Heroku don't provides A information, because the way it works. I've set an ALIAS to non-www, so both addresses works with no redirecting. I should implement the redirection server-side.

Comment: @JTWebMan I run Ghost on Heroku. I though about using NGinx, but until I configure it I may implement the redirect server-side.

Comment: Mateus best thing you can do is Nginx and redirect then if you can't use DNS and A records. It's not supported by Ghost afaik. You could change ghost but then that's not maintainable easily with future upgrades